# aria2 vs. aria2c?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request, tag-synonym-request

A proposed tag wiki edit raised a question about two tags: [aria2](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aria2) and [aria2c](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aria2c).  The first has 5 questions, the second has 8, and a number of these questions have both.

I'm not familiar with the program, but attempting to research it, I couldn't find a single word explaining the difference, and the terms are used interchangeably.  Web sites (including the official project sites), have a title containing one term and content containing the other, with no explanation.  My guess from the context is that aria2 is the project and aria2c is the executable.

The proposed wiki edits that raised the question were an attempt to copy the [aria2](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aria2) wiki and excerpt content to the [aria2c](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aria2c) tag.  This appears to be a case where the separate tags are not serving a useful purpose.

- Whatever the difference is between the two should be made clear in the tag wikis, and the excerpts should provide guidance on when to use each.
- If the difference is unimportant, the tags should be synonomized, or one of them eliminated and the two terms be covered in the remaining wiki and excerpt.

If I was familiar with the program, I would just fix it (and I'll be happy to do that if somebody can explain the difference).  So I'm raising the question so people familiar with it can either clarify or do the honors.

Comment: aria2c has a [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/aria2c) while aria2 [does not](https://linux.die.net/man/1/aria2).  I suspect you are right in that the "aria2c" is the "command" while "aria2" denotes the "project".  I think that we could quite happily synonymise and merge one into the other if we can decide which way to go.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to make `aria2c` a synonym of `aria2`. The site said I couldn't do it because reputation of 5 in the tag is required. It didn't come to my mind that I can post a meta question to request making them synonyms. I tried to answer some of the tagged questions to get required points and edited tag wiki.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[aria2c](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aria2c) has been merged into [aria2](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aria2) and a synonym created.

```
updating post history, 8 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 8 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 5 rows affected
updating Documentation tag proposal commitments, 0 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [aria2] and [aria2c] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym aria2c -> aria2 was approved!
```

Answer (score 8):

My understanding is the same as yours: both `aria2` and `aria2c` are used interchangeably. They should be synonymized.

The command you use to run the utility is `aria2c`. From that point of view, using it as the main tag looks more reasonable. At the same time, Google search gives much more results for `aria2`. Stack Overflow has only one tag: `aria2`.

To be consistent, `aria2` is the one to use as the main tag.

Comment: For word association, it seems like aria2 would be the more general term, encompassing any question related to the product, while aria2c might be thought of as relating to command syntax. For example, many programs can use run-time parameters with the executable name or have a command that's different from the product name, but we generally use the product name for the tag rather than the executable name or command. That would be another rationale for using aria2 for the tag.

Comment: @fixer1234 I agree *aria2* would cover both aspects: the project itself and usage of `aria2c` executable to perform a certain task.

Answer (score 7):

`aria2` is package name and `aria2c` is a binary file inside it. As you can see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/amd64/aria2/filelist), `aria2c` is the only executable file inside `aria2` package. Also its official website says:

> aria2 is a lightweight multi-protocol & multi-source command-line
>   download utility. It supports HTTP/HTTPS, FTP, SFTP, BitTorrent and
>   Metalink. aria2 can be manipulated via built-in JSON-RPC and XML-RPC
>   interfaces.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on which term would be better to use as the tag?

Comment: @fixer1234: I think `aria2` is a better choice. `aria2c` isn't as famous as tools like `apt-get` to have a tag for `aria2c`. There is similar situation about `sysstat` package which contains these binaries: sar, sadf, sadc, etc. In this case I prefer we have one tag named `sysstat` instead of multiple tags `sar` , `sadf` , `sadc` , etc